# Reset instance of singleton service angular 5

Tags: html, typescript

In my two different firm components I've used common instance of a service.

I want  to reset instance of singleton service. Is any built in function available?

Comment: You have XY problem. This isn't a correct approach. Basically not possible. Consider updating the question with relevant details that explain your case.

Comment: Use service at Component level, on module level. Learn more on hierarchy of angular service

Comment: ,So my problem statement is I've two forms which can be switched anytime , one is  less detailed form and other is more detailed form, i want to add functionality so that if user is filling detailed form but wish to go to less detailed one, the form filled earlier should remain as is and also common fields in both forms should get filled automatically in the less one, data of both forms should persist unless user switches to other url or reset forms.